# Is there a way to display HTML in silverlight without an iframe overlay?

Tags: .net, html, silverlight

I am trying to incorporate some HTML into a silverlight application however even commercial solutions such as C1 HtmlHost control use the widely discussed silverlight iframe overlay technique.

This technique means that any silverlight dialogs still have the HTML "floating" above them, I want dialogs in silverlight to appear above the HTML.

I have found a basic HTML renderer (C1 RichText Editor allows HTML importing to a point) that allows bolding, italic, tables etc within silverlight itself but no full blown solution. Does anyone know if there is a full HTML renderer that can run **inside** silverlight rather than on top of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is running out-of-browser you can use the browser component - if you want it inside your browser application you need to wait for silverlight 5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot to mention it is an application running in browser. I guess the only solution is to wait until Silverlight 5 then?